# How to get the percentage by using Cast(count and case statement) in SQL

Tags: sql

select cast((count(distinct case when birthdayattendance='yes' then Student_ID else null end)/count(distinct Student_ID))  as decimal(2,2))

```
 from #tmpcombined.

Issue : last step which is percentage is returning as 0.00 instead 0.50. There are two students out of 4 whose who attended school on their birthday.
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Some databases do integer division.  To prevent this, I just multiply by 1.0:

```
select (count(distinct case when birthdayattendancek = 'yes' then Student_ID end) * 1.0 /
        count(distinct Student_ID)
       )
```

`cast()`ing *after* the division just casts the results to a decimal.